# How to change and give permission on root folder directory?

Tags: permissions, directory, root

I use Codeigniter. 
My project folder is : **C:/wamp/www/hiro**
My project url : **localhost/hiro**
And my image folder : **C:/wamp/www/hiro/images**
So the url is **localhost/hiro/images** but I don't want to give access to this folder. IF user go to **localhost/hiro/images** i want to give no permission access.
The user profile url is : **localhost/hiro/profile/*username*** so I want to make user's image url is **localhost/hiro/profile/*username*/images/*image_name.jpg*** . 
My database will check image for this username. 
If user is logged in user can views **localhost/hiro/profile/*username*/images/*image_name.jpg*** if not give message no permission access.
How can I do? Please help :)

Comment: you have to upload image to the desire path. you can create folder dynamically with username

Comment: Oh, Yes It's expandable. But I want to give permission access just user login only. if not login no permission to access.

Comment: Use session to control login and logout. If there is session give permission. Using framework are easy for this tasks.